# Items not getting aligned properly CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navbar

I am making a website using React and here I am using html and css. I have got a nav bar and a search bar but the problem is that the search bar is changing the alignment of the title in the nav bar, here is the codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-pine-0x9t60?file=/src/App.js

Please make sure to increase the result size so that you can see it properly. Here, I want the title to be in the center, the search bar to be at the left and the menu icons to the right. Currently, the search bar is at the left, the menu icons are on the right, but the title isn't in the center. Please help me fix this problem. Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: Get rid of center tag. It is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Comment: @m4n0 but then also the problem is there.

Comment: Please note that questions you ask here are supposed to contain a proper [mre] of the issue directly inside the question, not just some link to an external platform (that might get invalidated at any time in the future, leaving the question here without context.)

Comment: @CBroe but the problem is that my code is too huge, and it is showing "please add more text, your post is mostly code"

Comment: easiest way it's using flexbox

Comment: Yeah, the problem will still be there because the code is messy. That was a suggestion.

Comment: @CyrusKabir can you please show ?

Comment: Learn this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @m4n0 can you please implement this in my code and show me ? I really don't know about this, and I am new to these kind of things

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/lH1S0G

Comment: _"but the problem is that my code is too huge"_ - what I referred you to, contains "minimal" in the title for a reason. You are not supposed to dump your whole code here, but to _reduce_ it to the minimal amount necessary to reproduce your problem. In a case like this, that could probably be done with a bit of HTML & CSS, and doesn't need most of that React stuff to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe okay, I got it, I will try to do that in my next questions

Comment: @m4n0, can you please send the updated code in the answer?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-ganguly-x2qmjk?file=/src/styles.css I would suggest you to stop doing the current way and resort to learning modern HTML and CSS before you move further. The code was already messy. I just made some corrections in HTML and CSS as per your requirement but it still requires much improvement. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had corrected your code by removing unneccesary margin/padding and adding flexx

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <nav class="header">
      <form action="" class="search-bar">
        <input
          type="search"
          name="search"
          pattern=".*\S.*"
          class="myinput"
          required
        />
        <button class="search-btn searchbtn" type="submit">
          <span>Search</span>
        </button>
      </form>
      <center>
        <a href="" class="logo">
          BEST FURNITURE
        </a>
      </center>

      <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
      <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
        <span class="navicon"></span>
      </label>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li style={{marginRight:'5px'}}>
          <center>
            <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
              <path
                fill="none"
                d="M17.671,13.945l0.003,0.002l1.708-7.687l-0.008-0.002c0.008-0.033,0.021-0.065,0.021-0.102c0-0.236-0.191-0.428-0.427-0.428H5.276L4.67,3.472L4.665,3.473c-0.053-0.175-0.21-0.306-0.403-0.306H1.032c-0.236,0-0.427,0.191-0.427,0.427c0,0.236,0.191,0.428,0.427,0.428h2.902l2.667,9.945l0,0c0.037,0.119,0.125,0.217,0.239,0.268c-0.16,0.26-0.257,0.562-0.257,0.891c0,0.943,0.765,1.707,1.708,1.707S10,16.068,10,15.125c0-0.312-0.09-0.602-0.237-0.855h4.744c-0.146,0.254-0.237,0.543-0.237,0.855c0,0.943,0.766,1.707,1.708,1.707c0.944,0,1.709-0.764,1.709-1.707c0-0.328-0.097-0.631-0.257-0.891C17.55,14.182,17.639,14.074,17.671,13.945 M15.934,6.583h2.502l-0.38,1.709h-2.312L15.934,6.583zM5.505,6.583h2.832l0.189,1.709H5.963L5.505,6.583z M6.65,10.854L6.192,9.146h2.429l0.19,1.708H6.65z M6.879,11.707h2.027l0.189,1.709H7.338L6.879,11.707z M8.292,15.979c-0.472,0-0.854-0.383-0.854-0.854c0-0.473,0.382-0.855,0.854-0.855s0.854,0.383,0.854,0.855C9.146,15.596,8.763,15.979,8.292,15.979 M11.708,13.416H9.955l-0.189-1.709h1.943V13.416z M11.708,10.854H9.67L9.48,9.146h2.228V10.854z M11.708,8.292H9.386l-0.19-1.709h2.512V8.292z M14.315,13.416h-1.753v-1.709h1.942L14.315,13.416zM14.6,10.854h-2.037V9.146h2.227L14.6,10.854z M14.884,8.292h-2.321V6.583h2.512L14.884,8.292z M15.978,15.979c-0.471,0-0.854-0.383-0.854-0.854c0-0.473,0.383-0.855,0.854-0.855c0.473,0,0.854,0.383,0.854,0.855C16.832,15.596,16.45,15.979,15.978,15.979 M16.917,13.416h-1.743l0.189-1.709h1.934L16.917,13.416z M15.458,10.854l0.19-1.708h2.218l-0.38,1.708H15.458z"
              ></path>
            </svg>
            <p style={{ fontSize: "0.6rem" }}>Cart</p>
          </center>
        </li>
        <li style={{marginRight:'5px'}}>
          <center>
            <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
              <path d="M18.125,15.804l-4.038-4.037c0.675-1.079,1.012-2.308,1.01-3.534C15.089,4.62,12.199,1.75,8.584,1.75C4.815,1.75,1.982,4.726,2,8.286c0.021,3.577,2.908,6.549,6.578,6.549c1.241,0,2.417-0.347,3.44-0.985l4.032,4.026c0.167,0.166,0.43,0.166,0.596,0l1.479-1.478C18.292,16.234,18.292,15.968,18.125,15.804 M8.578,13.99c-3.198,0-5.716-2.593-5.733-5.71c-0.017-3.084,2.438-5.686,5.74-5.686c3.197,0,5.625,2.493,5.64,5.624C14.242,11.548,11.621,13.99,8.578,13.99 M16.349,16.981l-3.637-3.635c0.131-0.11,0.721-0.695,0.876-0.884l3.642,3.639L16.349,16.981z"></path>
            </svg>
            <p style={{ fontSize: "0.6rem" }}>Search</p>
          </center>
        </li>
        <li style={{marginRight:'5px'}}>
          <center>
            <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
              <path d="M12.075,10.812c1.358-0.853,2.242-2.507,2.242-4.037c0-2.181-1.795-4.618-4.198-4.618S5.921,4.594,5.921,6.775c0,1.53,0.884,3.185,2.242,4.037c-3.222,0.865-5.6,3.807-5.6,7.298c0,0.23,0.189,0.42,0.42,0.42h14.273c0.23,0,0.42-0.189,0.42-0.42C17.676,14.619,15.297,11.677,12.075,10.812 M6.761,6.775c0-2.162,1.773-3.778,3.358-3.778s3.359,1.616,3.359,3.778c0,2.162-1.774,3.778-3.359,3.778S6.761,8.937,6.761,6.775 M3.415,17.69c0.218-3.51,3.142-6.297,6.704-6.297c3.562,0,6.486,2.787,6.705,6.297H3.415z"></path>
            </svg>
            <p style={{ fontSize: "0.6rem" }}>Account</p>
          </center>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

**style.css**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  font-size: 250%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}

.brlarge {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6em;
}

.svg-icon {
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
}

.svg-icon path,
.svg-icon polygon,
.svg-icon rect {
  fill: #4691f6;
}

.svg-icon circle {
  stroke: #4691f6;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

* {
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.searchbtn,
.myinput {
  font: 1em Hind, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.myinput {
  color: #171717;
}
.search-bar {
  
  float: left;
}

.search-bar .myinput,
.search-btn,
.search-btn:before,
.search-btn:after {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
.search-bar .myinput,
.search-btn {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
}
.search-bar .myinput:invalid:not(:focus),
.search-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-bar .myinput:focus,
.search-bar .myinput:valid {
  width: 50%;
}
.search-bar .myinput:focus,
.search-bar .myinput:not(:focus) + .search-btn:focus {
  outline: transparent;
}
.search-bar {
  padding: 1.5em;
  
  max-width: 30em;
}
.search-bar .myinput {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 1.5em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.4em #171717 inset;
  padding: 0.75em;
  transform: translate(0.5em, 0.5em) scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.search-bar .myinput::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.search-bar .myinput:focus,
.search-bar .myinput:valid {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.375em 0 0 0.375em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em #d9d9d9 inset;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.search-btn {
  background: #171717;
  border-radius: 0 0.75em 0.75em 0 / 0 1.5em 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0.75em;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(0.25em, 0.25em) rotate(45deg) scale(0.25, 0.125);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.search-btn:before,
.search-btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.search-btn:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em #f1f1f1 inset;
  top: 0.75em;
  left: 0.75em;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
}
.search-btn:after {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 0 0.25em 0.25em 0;
  top: 51%;
  left: 51%;
  width: 0.75em;
  height: 0.25em;
  transform: translate(0.2em, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}
.search-btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

/* Active state */
.search-bar .myinput:focus + .search-btn,
.search-bar .myinput:valid + .search-btn {
  background: #2762f3;
  border-radius: 0 0.375em 0.375em 0;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.search-bar .myinput:focus + .search-btn:before,
.search-bar .myinput:focus + .search-btn:after,
.search-bar .myinput:valid + .search-btn:before,
.search-bar .myinput:valid + .search-btn:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.search-bar .myinput:focus + .search-btn:hover,
.search-bar .myinput:valid + .search-btn:hover,
.search-bar .myinput:valid:not(:focus) + .search-btn:focus {
  background: #0c48db;
}
.search-bar .myinput:focus + .search-btn:active,
.search-bar .myinput:valid + .search-btn:active {
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .myinput {
    color: #000;
  }

  .search-bar .myinput {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.4em #000 inset;
  }
  .search-bar .myinput:focus,
  .search-bar .myinput:valid {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1em #3d3d3d inset;
  }
  .search-btn {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

> Just a small suggestion , replace `class` with `className` in App.js

Comment: Please remove the center tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can add these styles to your `.header` :

```
.header {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```